# How does the positional form and phase form of a body having simple harmonic motion relate to each other?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, linear-systems

A body which is connected to a spring end, has been pressed and released. It has possessed simple harmonic motion.
I was told its positional form and phase form would look something like the following picture-2 and picture-3.
Picture-2 is a graph which has shown the body's displacement vs time graph in which the displacement is actually a sin function and in the picture-3, the simple harmonic motion has been represented as a circular motion having angular velocity, displacement angle etc.
Now how does the positional form and phase form relate to each other?
The actual system of picture -1 is one dimensional and linear but the system in picture-3 is two dimensional and circular.[image: The actual system (picture-1), Positional form (picture-2) and Phase form (picture-3)]

Comment: This seems homework, so you should at least say what you did till now.

Comment: Can you tidy things up in your question a little? You use "wave form" and "phase form" in ways that are confusing.  I would suggest using exactly one word for each, probably drop the term "wave form" completely. Also, your figures have no axis labels, so it's tough to figure out what they are.  Also, maybe indicate what the period and max y value on pic-2 mean, and the max x and max y values in pic-3. If you do all that, you will be a large fraction of the way to answering your own question.

Comment: sorry. . . @Dan i have edited my question accordingly. i hope this would do now. thanks.

Comment: I hope you are not too frustrated by me not just giving you the answer. This is really high-school level homework stuff so not supposed to. It's not a phase-transition, as in your tag. It's a phase diagram. Can you write down the formula for y in pic-2 in terms of time? That is, how is x related to time?  Can you take the derivative of w.r.t. time of that formula for y? Then you will find that your pic-3 has sin for one axis and cos for the other, and is not a circle but has width A and height A w.

Answer (score 1):

The phase form you have drawn lacks one thing. The vertical axis is imaginary, so the graph represents the complex plane. The phase form is then the plot of the complex valued function $$A \ e^{i \omega t}$$

The relationship between the phase form and the position form is then either $$A \ \sin(\omega t)=\Im(A \ e^{i \omega t})$$ or $$A \ \cos(\omega t)=\Re(A \ e^{i \omega t})$$ depending on whether you are writing the position form in terms of $\sin$ or $\cos$.